# how to merge two branches which have no relation in svn. If yes how to write the commands through shell script

Tags: svn

Can we merge two branches which have no relation in svn. If yes how to write the commands through shell script.

I had two branches in SVN repository, which had no relation with each other. Can we merge those two branches(?)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the --ignore-ancestry option if you want to merge two unrelated branches. In my example you merge the delta from branch1 from rev X to rev. Y into branch2

Commands:

```
svn checkout URL_branch2 path/to/branch2
svn merge --ignore-ancestry -c X:Y URL_branch1 path/to/branch2
```

As the branches do not share any history you need to specify the commits you want to merge, as SVN cannot find the origin of the branch(as they do not have one..)